# How to import RegExp on angular 4 typescript

Tags: regex, angular6

```
import RegExp from "typescript-dotnet-commonjs/System/Text/RegularExpressions";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private whiteList = [
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8081/app2/oauth-server/oauth/token',
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/signup'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/registeration/confirm/.*'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/user/profile/upload'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/profile/edit/password/.*')
    ]}
```

The import is not working. It's saying can't find module.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing ')' on the first item of the array.

```
import RegExp from "typescript-dotnet-commonjs/System/Text/RegularExpressions";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private whiteList = [
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8081/app2/oauth-server/oauth/token'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/signup'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/registeration/confirm/.*'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/user/profile/upload'),
        new RegExp('http://localhost:8082/app/oauth-resource/ibex/api/profile/edit/password/.*')
    ]}
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is not with that. The issue is with the import on RegExp.